# A "play" symbol appears on my background video

Tags: javascript, html, css, iphone, web

I've created a page with a backgroud video. It works great on desktop, but when I check it works on iPhone, it doesn't play the video, but displays the "play" icon.
`<video type="video/mp4" src="background.mp4" autoplay muted loop playsinline id="vid"></video>`

Iphone page test

[image: 1]

I tried to start the video with js method video.play(). It didn't work

Comment: Autoplay doesn't work if your iPhone is low on battery / in power-saving mode. Try charging your phone and see if that solves your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autoplay doesn't work in power-saving mode. Just turned it off, video autoplay starts and "play" symbol disappeared.

Comment: Give a brief explanation of your response.